# Adding a scale to canvas image zoom

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using a some code from https://github.com/dimxasnewfrozen/Panning-Zooming-Canvas-Demos/blob/master/demo12/main.js (demo at http://dayobject.me/canvas/demo12/) to zoom in on an image using the Canvas element.

However, when zooming the jump between one zoom level and the next is too large, so I need to add a scale parameter.

How would I got about doing this?

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for testing this?

Comment: @choz - there is a demo at http://dayobject.me/canvas/demo12/ - I've added this to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It seams to me as if the algorithm always takes half of the dimension befor the zoom. At the end of you code you see it in **main.js** the **mouseWheel** function:

```
initialImageWidth = initialImageWidth * 2;
```

the width is divided by 2 so just change the used value.

You said the step used to zoom in and out is too big.

So I suggest that you generate the new value by using the dimensions of the image you want to zoom. For example you take a percentage of the biggest dimension of the current image.

That's how you can implement a zoom function that zooms according to the dimensions of the image

Answer (score 0):

In your `main.js`, you can change your zoomLevel here,

```
mouseWheel: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault() // Please add this, coz the scroll event bubbles up to document.
    var zoomLevel = 2;

    ...

    if (delta > 0) 
    {   
        // ZOOMING IN
        var zoomedX = canvasPos.deltaX - (canvasZoomX - canvasPos.deltaX);
        var zoomedY = canvasPos.deltaY - (canvasZoomY - canvasPos.deltaY);

        // scale the image up by 2
        initialImageWidth = initialImageWidth * zoomLevel;
    }
    else
    {   
        // ZOOMING OUT
        var zoomedX = (canvasPos.deltaX + canvasZoomX);
        var zoomedY = (canvasPos.deltaY + canvasZoomY);

        // scale the image down by 2
        initialImageWidth = initialImageWidth / zoomLevel;

    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: this ruins the `zoomedX` and `zoomedY` values. You gotta fix them :)*

Comment: @Snelfie What for? that variable is onlly called from `calculate_center()` which is only called once when canvas initialized. The OP wants to reduce the zoomLevel. Not calculate the center when the page loads.